# Query MySQL and FROM_UNIXTIME Epoch

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a problem when ordering an epoch field, it does not return the results ordered by date. Then I show you my code.

```
SELECT P.ID,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'nombrem' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS nombrem,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'generom' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS generom,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'tiempom' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS tiempom,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'urlm'    THEN PM.meta_value END) AS urlm,
    MAX(CASE WHEN PM.meta_key = 'imagenm' THEN PM.meta_value END) AS imagenm
FROM 
    K1nG_posts AS P
    LEFT JOIN K1nG_postmeta AS PM ON P.ID = PM.post_id 
WHERE 
    P.post_type = 'post' 
    AND (P.post_status = 'publish' OR P.post_status = 'private')  
GROUP BY P.ID, P.post_date ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME('tiempom')
```

The format of the "tiempom" field is as follows:

1570480237

I get the following error.

Warning: # 1292 Wrong truncated DECIMAL value: 'tiempom'

Comment: Please read: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308 and please create a https://www.db-fiddle.com/ replicating your issue.

Answer (score 0):

you can either

```
GROUP BY P.ID, P.post_date ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(tiempom)
```

or use backticks `

```
GROUP BY P.ID, P.post_date ORDER BY FROM_UNIXTIME(`tiempom`)
```

Because mysql thinks you want to convert the string 'tiempom' into a datetime .